# How to retrieve data from <td> within the same <tr> and output data to external div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of data consisting of 3 columns. In the third column is a button to click which should add data to the external div with the id of routeList from the first p in the second column. Here is my html. As well I have added a click event to change the class of the button and change the button text.

.html

```
<tr>
    <td class="col1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="..." class="img-responsive tableImage"></td>
    <td class="col2">
        <p class="address">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i> Address
        </p>
        <p>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i> Dates
        </p>
        <p>
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg"></i> Distance
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="col3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm routeAdd btn-success" data-toggle="addToRoute"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

.js

```
$('[data-toggle=addToRoute]').click(function() {
    if($(this).children().hasClass('fa-plus')) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-custom').addClass('btn-success').empty().html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Added');
            } else {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-custom').empty().html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add');
            }
        });
```

I was trying to add this to the first section of the if statement

```
$(this).closest('p.address').appendTo('#routeList');
```

I think I am missing something simple. As well on the flip side of the else statement the p should be removed if the button is clicked. Am I not selecting the element correctly. Or I am attacking this completely wrong.

Comment: full html please, or at least your code for the external div so we can find the most efficient method of doing what you want. does this div already have contents? do you want the data inserted somewhere specific within the div?

Comment: Basically it's just an empty external div. Eventually it will be another table of data with 2 columns one of the p.address and a button to remove that row altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('p.address').appendTo('#routeList');
```

Find `p.address` in closest `tr`.

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Yup that was the jquery call I was missing. On the else statement how can I erase that from the new div. Also I added .clone() before appendTo() so that original data stays put.

Comment: `$('#routeList').empty();` to remove all contents or `$('#routeList').find('p.address').remove();`

Comment: you can use `.html()` to overwrite any contents in the div, `.append()` to add content to the end of the current contents, or `.prepend()` to add content to the beginning. `.html('')` can also be used to empty the contents.

Comment: @tenub +1 for helpful comment.